# fortranでMPIを使って並列計算しようとしています

Tags: linux, fortran, mpi

> Fatal error in PMPI_Allgather: Invalid buffer pointer, error stack:
>   PMPI_Allgather(1093): MPI_Allgather(sbuf=0x2621ed0, scount=1,
>   MPI_INTEGER, rbuf=0x2621ed0, rcount=1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
>   failed PMPI_Allgather(1026): Buffers must not be aliased

上のようなエラーが出てしまうのですが，原因がわかりません．
何が原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: `Buffers must not be aliased` と表示されている事から、send buffer(sbuf) と receive buffer(rbuf) のアドレス値が同一(`0x2621ed0`)である事が原因と思われます。send と receive で同じバッファ領域を使うことはできない、という事ではないでしょうか。

Comment: http://accc.riken.jp/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/secure_4467_parallel-programming_main.pdf のP68参照 送信バッファーと受信バッファーはメモリ上で重なってはいけない。MPI2で導入された変数MPI_IN_PLACEを使用すれば、この制限を回避しうる。